# Custom post type conditional in loop

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I need multiple loops on a page and have created them as such

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'category' => 10 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?> "><?php the_title();?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have a custom post type (foo_post_type) which should be used as a conditional while the loop runs. For example, for each post in this loop:

```
if ('foo_post_type' == 'xyz' || 'foo_post_type' == '0' && 'category' => 10) {
 ...then display in the loop.....
}
```

But I am able to grab the custom post type for each post in the loop before the loop runs. And if I grab the custom post type during the loop it returns the same (usually incorrect) value. Where can I stick this foo_post_type in the loop shown at the top so it displays and evaluates each post bringing back the latest 3 which adhere to each condition?

(Unfortunately, I do not have a public link to the site.)

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to only display posts of a certain type within the loop? If so, you can add the `'post_type' => 'foo_post_type'` argument to your `get_posts` call and you'll only have posts with that type.

Comment: Thanks Andy. foo_post_type is a drop down with it's own selections. Can I do an arg like:

`'post_type' => 'foo_post_type' => 'foo1'`

Comment: that shouldn't matter. Presumably `foo_post_type` is available *inside* your custom loop, so it should also be available *before* you instantiate it, right?

Comment: Chris - yes, that's true. A better way to say it is that I want to push this: 
`'foo_post_type' == 'xyz' || 'foo_post_type' == '0' && 'category' => 10` into my $args statement. I've tried various ways but cannot get it to obey my request!

Comment: So is 'foo_post_type' a custom taxonomy attached to your custom post type? It's hard to tell from your heavily abstracted code.

Comment: Yes, sorry, definitely don't want to be cryptic. foo_post_type is a drop down with options, I don't know if that classifies as a custom taxonomy.